# Using Google ML to retrain Image Recognition with TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm using a bunch of images to train my Tensorflow Image recognition project using this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#4

Actually I need a lot of Cpu to train my model and it takes a lot of time on my laptop.

I have registered a Google ML account and started this tutorial: 
https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/training

Everything is set up and running but this is for mnist sample code. There is no image_retraining sample code like the retrain.py from [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html#image-recognition).

Looking for some examples on how to to run the [Tensorflow Image Recognition script retrain](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#4) in Google ML.